# Facebook pin post option disappear

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Two day ago has disappeared the pin and unpin post option from Facebook group

I created a group of Facebook 5 years ago. I put another administrator too. I used to pin post that I consider important but since 2 day ago I don't find the pin option.

Moreover, I had pinned a post before that problem. So there is a pinned post that I can't unpinned too.

[image: Pin Post Disappeared image]

Where is now? What can I do?

Comment: Facebook Help says that that's still the way to do it. I suspect it's a bug that'll be rectified soon. In the meantime, you should use the "Report a Problem" form to let them know.

Comment: I have talked with the other admin and he could unpin the last pinned post from his smartphone. But I still can't pin or unpin post and He didn't try pin or unpin post from a Desktop browser. I will try _Report a Problem_. Thanks @AʟE.

Comment: Having the feature available in the smartphone app but not in the desktop site almost certainly means this is a bug that they'll fix soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@Aʟ E.` has mentioned in a [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98807/facebook-pin-post-option-disappear#comment85805_98807), it is a bug. People have been facing this issue for a long time. Hopefully they will fix this soon. Meantime, you can [Report a Problem](https://www.facebook.com/help/186570224871049) to Facebook.

See the same issue on [the Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200933362193014).